# Saving file as a TXT file and Open the file as same format in PHP

Tags: php, file

I have the following php file which takes some form values and writes to a text file and creates a format which is easy for viewing:

```
$filename = "blah.txt"; #Must CHMOD to 666, set folder to 777
$text = "\n" . str_pad($fname, 30) . "" . str_pad($lname, 30) . "" . str_pad($tdate, 20) . "" . str_pad($ydept, 30) . "" . str_pad($percentage, 0) . "%";

$fp = fopen ($filename, "a"); # a = append to the file. w = write to the file (create new if doesn't exist)
if ($fp) {
    fwrite ($fp, $text);
    fclose ($fp);
    #echo ("File written");
}
else {
    #echo ("File was not written");
}
```

The text file which was already created has a pre-format which looks something like this:

```
                        @@@@@@ CLINICAL EXAM @@@@@@

First Name                    Last Name                     Date Taken          Department                    Percentage
==========                    =========                     ==========          ==========                    ==========
```

And as new records are being written, it will look something like this:

```
                        @@@@@@ CLINICAL EXAM @@@@@@

First Name                    Last Name                     Date Taken          Department                    Percentage
==========                    =========                     ==========          ==========                    ==========

Lolll                         Pelol                         02/13/13            Nursing                       92%
Catger                        Powhytr                       02/13/13            Nursing                       92%
```

As new user takes the exam it will keep appending to the existing file.
I want to setup an authentication so it requries a username/password to view the file and keep the format. The authentication I can setup by using an include(); method on top of the php file which reads the text file. I have something of the following code which reads the file:

```
 <?php
    $filename = "blah.txt";
    $file = $filename;
    $contents = file($file); 
    $string = implode("<br>", $contents); 
    echo "<pre>" . $string . "</pre>";
    echo "<br></br>";
?>
```

This displays the following:

```
@@@@@@ CLINICAL EXAM @@@@@@ 

First Name Last Name Date Taken Department Percentage 
========== ========= ========== ========== ========== 

Lilll Pelol 02/13/13 Nursing 92% 
Catger Powhytr 02/13/13 Nursing 92%
```

What I like to do is display the format that it saves in so the it makes it readable to the user. How can I accomplish this?
I am trying to do it because keeping a text file on the web makes it visible for everyone and it's a security issue.

Comment: That's the difference between HTML and plain text. What do you want to generate?

Comment: I want to let the user view the text file after going through authentication and not allowing to see the location of the text file and keep the same format.

Comment: Wrap the file display in <pre> tags, without using your <br> explode

Comment: I updated the code as Kolink mentioned below and it is displaying the same way it's writing :)

Comment: @SiKni8 - That doesn't answer my question but I guess you don't really care about the output format :)

Comment: LOL @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Sorry I was just too excited to have gotten the help so quick. I don't mind just displaying the text in the php file with the same format and no access to the location of the text file. Thank you :)

Comment: One question remains is... How do I create a login with username/password on the php file so it is required each time someone tries to access the file. and directs them to the proper files(I have two and they can choose from the pull down menu) Should I ask a different question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are outputting the file to the browser, you must use `<pre>...</pre>` around the file contents (or alternatively an element with `font-family:monospace; white-space:pre`) otherwise the spaces will be collapsed.

Note in your original code that `. "" .` is a no-op and therefore can be removed, leaving just `.`

Also, I would suggest this instead of all the `str_pad` calls:

```
$text = sprintf("\n%-30s%-30s%-20s%-30s%s%%",$fname,$lname,$tdate$ydept,$percentage);
```

Comment: KOLINK... you are the man!!!! all I had to do is include the "<pre>" before and "</pre>" after the string displayed and it kept the same exact format... THANKS!!!!!!! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. For future reference, always check what you get when you right-click and View Source.

Comment: This answer applies if you are injecting the file into an HTML document (i.e., inside some `<body>` tag). Browsers can of course display plain text perfectly, you just need to send an appropriate `Content-Type` header.